# Deleting part of the cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I write the formula in Excel to delete everything after the * including it? Both texts before and after the * are random sized.

Cell A1: adlkjadflaskd*kljadkfjasdkfjhas

Cell A2: adslfkjasdfçlkjlkjlksjdflsdfs*309982409

Cell A3: lkaçlaskjdfçklsadjf*sdakdaçsdlkfjaçslkdf

Result to be:

Cell B1: adlkjadflaskd

Cell B2: adslfkjasdfçlkjlkjlksjdflsdfs

Cell B3: lkaçlaskjdfçklsadjf

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the LEFT and FIND functions:

```
 =LEFT(A1,FIND("*",A1& "*")-1)
```

The find finds the location of the `*` and returns that as the length desired to the LEFT.

Comment: Hello, formula is working ok except in the case that there is no * in the A1. How could fix this? and if I need to do same thing with & character as well, how could add it there? Thanks so much

Comment: @Joao see edits

Comment: Hello, it works fine now, thanks. Last thing i need to do is that if cell doesnt have * but instead has symbol & then it should do the same thing but to the right. Should I open another post or if possible could help me with this also here appreciate. Thanks

Comment: New questions get new posts.

Comment: @Joao one thing I have noticed, you have asked a lot of question and gotten a lot of answers.  When you get a correct answer you need to mark it as such by clicking the check mark by the answer that you used.  It is important you do this or people will stop answering your questions.  Please go back through your history and mark the answers that are correct as such.

Comment: Hello Scott, have marked the check. What does that number above it means? tks

Comment: The number above is upvotes/downvotes done by the community at large.  If someone in the community decides that it is a good question/answer then they can upvote it.  In this instance two people have decided that this answer is good and have upvoted it.  @Joao  Now you need to go back through your history and check the correct answers of your past questions also.